# jQuery using multiple library. there is a conflict error.

Tags: jquery

First script for corousel

```
<script>
  jQuery.noConflict(); 
  /* calling thumbnailScroller function with options as parameters */
  (function($){
  window.onload=function(){ 
      $("#tS3").thumbnailScroller({ 
        scrollerType:"clickButtons", 
        scrollerOrientation:"vertical", 
        scrollSpeed:2, 
        scrollEasing:"easeOutCirc", 
        scrollEasingAmount:800, 
        acceleration:4, 
        scrollSpeed:800, 
        noScrollCenterSpace:10, 
        autoScrolling:0, 
        autoScrollingSpeed:2000, 
        autoScrollingEasing:"easeInOutQuad", 
        autoScrollingDelay:500 
      });
  }
  })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Second script for inline pop up:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.fancybox').fancybox();
    });
</script>
```

How to combine both with out conflict error, I get its very simple, but I am new to jQuery.

Comment: Your second script won't fly if you're trying to use jQuery, because you used `noConflict()`, so the `$` variable no longer refers to jQuery.

Comment: @gpgekko its not true as OP used in a scope so there should not be any issue. it in **Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)**

Comment: @Jai His second script is not inside that scope.

Comment: jquery undefined is the error(latest version of jquery is referenced). I am finding it difficult to understand noconflict and implementing it on this project. Could anyone combine these scripts for me?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to combine them, just combine them. From the limited information you've given, it would look like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery.noConflict();
  (function($) {
      $("#tS3").thumbnailScroller({
        scrollerType:"clickButtons",
        scrollerOrientation:"vertical",
        scrollSpeed:2,
        scrollEasing:"easeOutCirc",
        scrollEasingAmount:800,
        acceleration:4,
        scrollSpeed:800,
        noScrollCenterSpace:10,
        autoScrolling:0,
        autoScrollingSpeed:2000,
        autoScrollingEasing:"easeInOutQuad",
        autoScrollingDelay:500
      });
      $('.fancybox').fancybox();
  })(jQuery);
</script>
```